# I am having trouble to import Bootstrap styles into a vue-cli project

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-cli-3

I am suffering a lot to do something ridiculous here on my study project based on `Vue-CLI`

I really cannot understand why can't I `import` `Bootstrap` styles in my project.

**This is my `main.js` file:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' //here is where the app breaks
import {store} from "./store/store";
import {routes} from "./routes";

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

export const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if(savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    }
    if (to.hash) {
      return {selector: to.hash}
    }
    return {x: 0, y: 0};
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
router,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

**this is the error**

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module parse failed: /Users/Dev/WebstormProjects/stock-trading-app/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css Unexpected token (7:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| /*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
| html {
|   font-family: sans-serif;
|   -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 @ ./src/main.js 5:0-42
 @ multi main
```

I have installed `bootstrap` in my project through the following code in the terminal: `npm install --save bootstrap`.

When I enter the code line where I import `bootstrap` styles the app breaks...

Something kind of weird as well is that some `bootstrap` styling is working even though I do not have it imported. Even if I remove `BootstrapVue` from `main.js` some styling will still work.

For instance, I have experimented creating a `button` using the `class` `button.btn.btn-primary` and it works, even without any importing in main.js file...

The point is that  when I try to add a Bootstrap-vue dropdown button, namely `<b-dropdown>`  (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown/) it does not work...

In case anyone needs more info in order to help me out I will keep editing the question in order to add as much info as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Just created a new project, did the imports the same way as your code and everything works fine. Make sure that you are using the latest versions of both vue-cli and bootstrap, maybe you've got a bad release in one. Also try restarting `npm run serve`, deleting up node_modules and reinstalling...

Comment: As a sidenote, don't forget to include `import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'` as stated in the [Getting started section](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/)

Comment: @yuriy636 Yep I have done it as you can see above, specially noted on the error message... When I have this line added everything crashes. And as I had mentioned above, I have experimented removing both ```bootstrap styles``` and ```bootstrap-vue``` from ```main.js``` file and it turned out that I could access the built-in ```bootstrap``` ```styles``` in my components, although I did not manage to use ```<b-dropdown>```. How come this would be possible after all? This is weird. I have also tried restarting the development server. I will start a new project and try again..

Comment: @yuriy636 I have noticed that if I start a new project through Webstorm I can run the development server using ```npm run serve```, but if I build a development environment opening a folder with existing files, then afterwards installing ```npm``` dependencies I run de development server using ```npm run dev```, which was the case here. What is the difference and what is the best choice?

Comment: `npm run dev` used to be the pre-vue-cli-3 way, when you would use "templates" such as the [webpack one](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack). It's either that or the project exposes the internal webpack dev-server, which could be is not passing through vue's config, so that could explain the issues with css files. Could you post your package.json?

Comment: @yuriy636 I guess it all starts to make sense now. I am getting these files to have them built into ```vue-cli``` form an Udemy course that had been made at the time that ```vue-cli``` was version 3. I guess that this has made all of the nightmare happen, as the ```package.json``` file is from that version... So, in this case, what would you reccomend? I have already deleted the whole deal, before I read your comment...to bad. What should I do, build a new project from scratch in webstorm then replace these src files inside the new project?